# Function click on li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu with li elements, after click on the one of the elements I like to run a function click and display alert with an id of li element.

JS

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mainmenu li").click(function() {
       alert(this.id); 
    });
  </script>
```

HTML

```
    <div id="menu1">
    <ul id="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="#">Choose the first map <i class="arrow"></i></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Category 1<i class="arrow"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="div1clear" id="firstIDtoDisplay" data-path="contents/work/cycling1.html"><a href="#">% of employees cycling to work</a></li>                 
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Ethnic maps<i class="arrow"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="div1clear" id="secoundIDtoDisplay" data-path="contents/ethnic/white_british1.html"><a href="#">% of White British residents</a></li>
                    <li class="div1clear" id="thirdIDtoDisplay" data-path="contents/ethnic/white_tot1.html"><a href="#">% of White residents</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#mainmenu li").click(function() {
           alert(this.id); 
        });
      </script>



     <div id="menu1">
     <ul id="mainmenu">
     <li><a href="#">Choose the first map <i class="arrow"></i></a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Category 1<i class="arrow"></i></a>
        <ul>
         <li class="div1clear" id="firstIDtoDisplay" data-path="contents/work/cycling1.html"><a href="#">% of employees cycling to work</a></li>     
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Ethnic maps<i class="arrow"></i></a>
        <ul>
         <li class="div1clear" id="secoundIDtoDisplay" data-path="contents/ethnic/white_british1.html"><a href="#">% of White British residents</a></li>
         <li class="div1clear" id="thirdIDtoDisplay" data-path="contents/ethnic/white_tot1.html"><a href="#">% of White residents</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately after click nothing happens. No errors in console as well.
Probably the mistake is in a JS code, do you have an idea what is an issue?

Comment: You have to bind event once elements are available in DOM. Wrap it in document ready handler or set it before `<body/>` closing tag

Comment: wrap code in `$(function(){ /* code*/})` so elements exist when it runs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/pgsf6fot/

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#mainmenu li").click(function() {
          alert( $(this).attr('id') ); 
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi, your solution works, but besides alert with clicked id element I get also empty alerts of li elements those are above my clicked li element. Any solution how to prevent display this additional alerts?

Comment: you want the id's of "li" or the "a" tags?

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options here to solve your issue:
1- Put your JS code after the html element you need to bind too.
2- Use document.ready to make the js code execute after all html render.
3- Use [On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: You should provide example as how `.on()` method could fix issue here

Comment: `$("...").on("eventName", function(){...})` why should we use this if other function do the same job, like `.click(...)`?

Comment: He needs to use on if the html is rendering after the page finish rendering using an ajax request, and in some special cases he can't move the js to the bottom of the page and in this case ON can help as well.

Answer (score 1):

use on event for dynamic elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mainmenu").on("click","li",function() {
        alert(this.id); 
    });

});
```

Comment: You aren't delegating event here

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L3nxpaeL/4/  Event ins't delegated, check DOC, you need to pass selector param, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/L3nxpaeL/6/

Comment: @A.Wolff , I modified the answer , is it still worng?

Comment: Still your edit wouldn't fix issue, `#mainmenu` not available in DOM at time of binding event (otherwise OP's code would work too)

Comment: @A.Wolff ,, why dont you think , DOM ready wont solve the issue ? I edited.

Comment: I never said document ready won't fix issue... You talk about delegating event without delegating it before you edit your answer.

Comment: @A.Wolff Can you say now the answer is ok ?

Comment: Ya, now it will work and btw you avoid using multiple bound handlers by just using one, delegated at UL level. So imho, it is better way. But i guess, you should stop event propagation because it is quite unclear which LI should fire event regarding OP's code (not all LIs have an ID attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Might just be a matter of timing, the DOM might not be ready when your JS is executed. So you register the click events on elements that does not exists at that time, because they have not yet been rendered.

Try wrapping with a DOM ready listener (http://api.jquery.com/ready/), this will hold the executing of your JS until the DOM has been rendered.

```
$(function() {
    $("#mainmenu li").click(function() {
        alert(this.id); 
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
 
  $("#mainmenu li ul li ul li").click(function() {
           alert(this.id); 
        });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu1">
     <ul id="mainmenu">
     <li><a href="#">Choose the first map <i class="arrow"></i></a>
      <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Category 1<i class="arrow"></i></a>
        <ul>
         <li class="div1clear" id="firstIDtoDisplay" data-path="contents/work/cycling1.html"><a href="#">% of employees cycling to work</a></li>     
        </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Ethnic maps<i class="arrow"></i></a>
        <ul>
         <li class="div1clear" id="secoundIDtoDisplay" data-path="contents/ethnic/white_british1.html"><a href="#">% of White British residents</a></li>
         <li class="div1clear" id="thirdIDtoDisplay" data-path="contents/ethnic/white_tot1.html"><a href="#">% of White residents</a></li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, your solution works, but besides alert with clicked id element I get also empty alerts of li elements those are above my clicked li element in ul list. Any solution how to prevent display this additional alerts?

Comment: So bind event only for LI with ID set and stop propagation: `$(function(){
    $("#mainmenu").on("click","li[id]",function(e) { e.stopPropagation();
        alert(this.id); 
    });
});`   http://jsfiddle.net/xpqmb2vr/

Answer (score -3):

Specify the id attribute of the click li using $(this), and return false to cancel any propagation and the default behaviour of li

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#mainmenu li").click(function(e) {
       alert($(this).attr('id')); 
       return false;
    });
  </script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ptx2hwy3/